# random walk with absolute value

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Given a simple random walk with $S_0 = 0$ and p = q = $\frac{1}{2}$. Find $P(|S_n| \leq 1)$ for n = 1, 2, 3..., N where N is an even number. Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. $\ S_n\ $ is odd when $\ n\ $ is odd, and even when $\ n\ $ is even.
2. If $\ S_n = m\ $ then $\ \frac{m+n}{2}\ $ of the first $\ n\ $ steps must have been to the right and $\ \frac{n-m}{2}\ $ of them must have been to the left.
3. The number of rightward steps among the first $\ n\ $ follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $\ n\ $ and $\frac{1}{2}\ $.
4. If $\ \left\vert S_n\right\vert\le 1\ $ and $\ n\ $ is even then $\ S_n\ $ must be $\ 0\ $.  If $\ \left\vert S_n\right\vert\le 1\ $ and $\ n\ $ is odd then $\ S_n\ $ must be either$\ +\hspace{-0.3em}1\ $ or $\ -\hspace{-0.3em}1\ $.